# yolo_head when evaluates model gives: Attribute Error: list object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: deep-learning, attributeerror, yolo, dtype

Sorry, Im new to this, but I can't find the answer anywhere. 
I am trying to implement a yolo car detection on my computer, but I'm getting this error and not sure what to do.

Here is the code

````
sess = tf.keras.backend.get_session()


##detect 80 classes, usng 5 anchor boxes; 729x1280 images which are processed to 608x608 images

class_names = read_classes("model_data/coco_classes.txt")
anchors = read_anchors("model_data/yolo_anchors.txt")
image_shape = (720., 1280.)

#load the model
yolo_model = load_model("model_data/yolo.h5", compile = False)


#convert output of the model to usable bounding box tensors
yolo_outputs = yolo_head(yolo_model.output, anchors, len(class_names))```
````

And here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yolo.py", line 232, in <module>
    yolo_outputs = yolo_head(yolo_model.output, anchors, len(class_names))
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\PYTHON\tensor\cardetect\yad2k\models\keras_yolo.py", line 113, in yolo_head
    conv_index = K.cast(conv_index, K.dtype(feats))
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\PYTHON\tensor\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 905, in dtype
    return x.dtype.base_dtype.name
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

And here is the yolo_head code, I don't know if that's important

```
def yolo_head(feats, anchors, num_classes):
    """Convert final layer features to bounding box parameters.

    Parameters
    ----------
    feats : tensor
        Final convolutional layer features.
    anchors : array-like
        Anchor box widths and heights.
    num_classes : int
        Number of target classes.

    Returns
    -------
    box_xy : tensor
        x, y box predictions adjusted by spatial location in conv layer.
    box_wh : tensor
        w, h box predictions adjusted by anchors and conv spatial resolution.
    box_conf : tensor
        Probability estimate for whether each box contains any object.
    box_class_pred : tensor
        Probability distribution estimate for each box over class labels.
    """
    num_anchors = len(anchors)
    # Reshape to batch, height, width, num_anchors, box_params.
    anchors_tensor = K.reshape(K.variable(anchors), [1, 1, 1, num_anchors, 2])
    # Static implementation for fixed models.
    # TODO: Remove or add option for static implementation.
    # _, conv_height, conv_width, _ = K.int_shape(feats)
    # conv_dims = K.variable([conv_width, conv_height])

    # Dynamic implementation of conv dims for fully convolutional model.
    conv_dims = K.shape(feats)[1:3]  # assuming channels last
    # In YOLO the height index is the inner most iteration.
    conv_height_index = K.arange(0, stop=conv_dims[0])
    conv_width_index = K.arange(0, stop=conv_dims[1])
    conv_height_index = K.tile(conv_height_index, [conv_dims[1]])

    # TODO: Repeat_elements and tf.split doesn't support dynamic splits.
    # conv_width_index = K.repeat_elements(conv_width_index, conv_dims[1], axis=0)
    conv_width_index = K.tile(K.expand_dims(conv_width_index, 0), [conv_dims[0], 1])
    conv_width_index = K.flatten(K.transpose(conv_width_index))
    conv_index = K.transpose(K.stack([conv_height_index, conv_width_index]))
    conv_index = K.reshape(conv_index, [1, conv_dims[0], conv_dims[1], 1, 2])
    conv_index = K.cast(conv_index, K.dtype(feats))

    feats = K.reshape(feats, [-1, conv_dims[0], conv_dims[1], num_anchors, num_classes + 5])
    conv_dims = K.cast(K.reshape(conv_dims, [1, 1, 1, 1, 2]), K.dtype(feats))

    # Static generation of conv_index:
    # conv_index = np.array([_ for _ in np.ndindex(conv_width, conv_height)])
    # conv_index = conv_index[:, [1, 0]]  # swap columns for YOLO ordering.
    # conv_index = K.variable(
    #     conv_index.reshape(1, conv_height, conv_width, 1, 2))
    # feats = Reshape(
    #     (conv_dims[0], conv_dims[1], num_anchors, num_classes + 5))(feats)

    box_confidence = K.sigmoid(feats[..., 4:5])
    box_xy = K.sigmoid(feats[..., :2])
    box_wh = K.exp(feats[..., 2:4])
    box_class_probs = K.softmax(feats[..., 5:])

    # Adjust preditions to each spatial grid point and anchor size.
    # Note: YOLO iterates over height index before width index.
    box_xy = (box_xy + conv_index) / conv_dims
    box_wh = box_wh * anchors_tensor / conv_dims

    return box_confidence, box_xy, box_wh, box_class_probs
```

I don't know if I'm missing some crucial detail, but can't find an aswer anywhere and I've tried some things, but to no avail. tell me if I need to add some more information, I'd appreciate any direction.

I should probably also add that this is the import section:

```
import argparse
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
import scipy.io
import scipy.misc
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import PIL
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Conv2D
from keras.models import load_model, Model
from yolo_utils import read_classes, read_anchors, generate_colors, preprocess_image, draw_boxes, scale_boxes
from yad2k.models.keras_yolo import yolo_head, yolo_boxes_to_corners, preprocess_true_boxes, yolo_loss, yolo_body
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

As you can see I disable tensorflow 2 to work as V1 cause this is some old code. I suspect that my version of keras and tensorflow are the issue, but it would be great if I could avoid downgrading, or if somebody could explain to me what the problem is, so I can work around it somehow. This code worked in Jupyter book so I don't know why it's failing me now.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem recently. Firstly I assume that your code and weights(yolo.h5) is copied from Doctor Andrew Ng's course " yolo car detection". I try to print the yolo.output and it is like :

```
[<tf.Tensor 'conv2d_59/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, ?, ?, 255) dtype=float32>]
```

and the solution is found here
[yolo_head_solution](https://github.com/dudeperf3ct/DL_Notebooks/blob/master/Object%20Detection/Keras/object_detection_keras.ipynb)
Basically he changed changed feats into feats[0]

And Secondly, which is the condition I meet. I copy the code from coursera, And then download the weights  from darknet. And the variable yolo_model.output is different from the former one , which is

```
[<tf.Tensor 'conv2d_59/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, ?, ?, 255) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'conv2d_67/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, ?, ?, 255) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'conv2d_75/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, ?, ?, 255) dtype=float32>]
```

So the solution is to change yolo_eval([the code is from here](https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3)) :

```
def yolo_eval(yolo_outputs,
          anchors,
          num_classes,
          image_shape,
          max_boxes=20,
          score_threshold=.6,
          iou_threshold=.5):
"""Evaluate YOLO model on given input and return filtered boxes."""
num_layers = len(yolo_outputs)
anchor_mask = [[6,7,8], [3,4,5], [0,1,2]] if num_layers==3 else [[3,4,5], [1,2,3]] # default setting
input_shape = K.shape(yolo_outputs[0])[1:3] * 32
boxes = []
box_scores = []
for l in range(num_layers):
    #here called yolo_head
    _boxes, _box_scores = yolo_boxes_and_scores(yolo_outputs[l],
        anchors[anchor_mask[l]], num_classes, input_shape, image_shape)
    boxes.append(_boxes)
    box_scores.append(_box_scores)
boxes = K.concatenate(boxes, axis=0)
box_scores = K.concatenate(box_scores, axis=0)

mask = box_scores >= score_threshold
max_boxes_tensor = K.constant(max_boxes, dtype='int32')
boxes_ = []
scores_ = []
classes_ = []
for c in range(num_classes):
    # TODO: use keras backend instead of tf.
    class_boxes = tf.boolean_mask(boxes, mask[:, c])
    class_box_scores = tf.boolean_mask(box_scores[:, c], mask[:, c])
    nms_index = tf.image.non_max_suppression(
        class_boxes, class_box_scores, max_boxes_tensor, iou_threshold=iou_threshold)
    class_boxes = K.gather(class_boxes, nms_index)
    class_box_scores = K.gather(class_box_scores, nms_index)
    classes = K.ones_like(class_box_scores, 'int32') * c
    boxes_.append(class_boxes)
    scores_.append(class_box_scores)
    classes_.append(classes)
boxes_ = K.concatenate(boxes_, axis=0)
scores_ = K.concatenate(scores_, axis=0)
classes_ = K.concatenate(classes_, axis=0)

return boxes_, scores_, classes_
```

Comment: Nice, finally an answer, can't wait to try this out, I'll respond with results. 
My Yolo.h5 weights aren't from his course, cause I can't download them for some reason, so I just downloaded some weights from online, figured it should still work since it's for the same purpose. PARAMS are a bit different, I think there's like 20000 more of them, think that's a problem? I mean all of coursera code is from the YOLO darknet website so figured it should still work. I'll try your solution see what happens. Maybe you know where I can download Andrews weight file, cause Coursera doesn't let me.